# Combine values in one array by condition in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an arrays like this
array

```
$array1 = array('key1'=>5,'key2'=>1,'key3'=>1);
```

output expected

```
 $array1 = array('key1'=>5);
```

another exambles
array

```
$array2 = array('key1'=>1,'key2'=>1,'key3'=>1);
```

output expected

```
$array2 = array('key1'=>1);
```

another example array

```
$array3 = array('key1'=>1,'key2'=>1,'key3'=>2,'key4'=>1);
```

output expected

```
$array3 = array('key3'=>2);
```

my condition is
 if the values in the array are 1, any one of the key value is the result for that array
if the value of the array are 1 except one key value, result is that particular key value

Is this possible?

Comment: i didn't understand what you are expecting but for remove duplicated we can use array_unique function

Comment: Do you care about the key or do you only care about the value? If the latter, you can merely do `max($array1);` for instance.

Comment: If the array values are 1 I need only one key value pair in that array. and the array has one value as another any one of the number otherwise all the values are 1

Comment: I care about both the key and value @Phylogenesis

Comment: try to be more specific

Comment: Something like [this](http://ideone.com/DFoKNI)?

Comment: @Phylogenesis got it right !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are specific to only 1 duplicate value try below logic or
if you are looking max value and key as mentioned @Phylogenesis use [this](http://ideone.com/DFoKNI) logic

```
$array1 = array('key1'=>5,'key2'=>1,'key3'=>1);
$array2 = array('key1'=>1,'key2'=>1,'key3'=>1);
$array3 = array('key1'=>1,'key2'=>1,'key3'=>2,'key4'=>1);


$array1 = filterArray($array1);
$array2 = filterArray($array2);
$array3 = filterArray($array3);

print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
print_r($array3);

function filterArray($array)
{
    $newArray = [];
    if (in_array(1, array_values($array))) {

        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if ($val != 1) {
                $newArray[$key] = $val;
                break;
            }


        }
        if (empty($newArray)) {
            $newArray['key1'] = 1;
        }
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

Comment: thanks i think it may work for me. I figured out something else